# Создание ошибки на моменте компиляции собственного класса

Tags: c++, ооп, компиляция

Как сделать так, чтобы при создании объекта(собственного класса) и его инициализации неправильным значением, к примеру, меньше 0(-23), выдавалась ошибка на моменте компиляции программы?

Comment: Вы хотите создать собственную ошибку?

Comment: Всё верно, я хочу, чтобы при введении неправильного значения, оно подчёркивалось ещё на моменте компиляции

Comment: Язык бы указали, хотя бы ради приличия. Вангую, это C++

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, я забыл, сначала написал, но потом удалил. Да, это c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать можно, если использовать шаблон:

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr void f() 
{
  static_assert(N == 42, "ERROR TEXT");
}
```

Пример на [ideone](https://ideone.com/pHEvuX)